# Why won't this loop load the proper event?

Tags: c++, loops, root-framework

Here is the code I wrote, and it runs fine, but it doesn't seem to actually load the events ... instead, it seems to fill the histograms and the cout with one arbitrary miniscule number.

```
include "TTree.h"
include "TFile.h"
include "TRandom.h"
include "TTree.h"
include "TCanvas.h"
include "TStyle.h"
include <iostream>
include "TH1.h"
include "TChain.h"

using namespace std;

void readtestsimple(){

  TFile *file = TFile::Open("/file/");

  TTree* comp_tree = (TTree*)file->Get("_compress_tree");

  TChain* compchain = new TChain("_compress_tree");
  compchain->Add("/file/");

  TH1D *comp = new TH1D("comp","_compression",100,0,0.05);

  Double_t _compression, _compressionU, _compressionV, _compressionY, _ch_compression;
  Int_t _ch;
  comp_tree->SetBranchAddress("_compression",&_compression);
  comp_tree->SetBranchAddress("_compressionU",&_compressionU);
  comp_tree->SetBranchAddress("_compressionV",&_compressionV);
  comp_tree->SetBranchAddress("_compressionY",&_compressionY);

      Long64_t nentries = compchain->GetEntries();
      Long64_t nb = 0, nbytes = 0 ;

      for (Long64_t i=0; i<nentries; i++) {
              Long64_t entry = compchain->LoadTree(i);
              if (entry <0 ) break;

             nb = compchain->GetEntry(i); nbytes += nb;

              cout << "entry = " << nb << endl;
              cout << "compression = " << _compression << endl;

              comp->Fill(_compression);
      }

   cout << "entries = " << nentries << endl;

}
```

And the output I get is a long repetition of this:

```
entry = 36
compression = 1.54768e-316

entry = 36
compression = 1.54768e-316

entry = 36
compression = 1.54768e-316
```

(and at the end, the correct number of entries).

What do I do to make it read out the correct entry?
Please help!

Comment: I suggest you to post this on the [root forum](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/), maybe there you will get less downvotes and more help ;)

Comment: your code seems redundant. either open the `TFile` and `Get` the `TTree` within, or (especially if your data is spread over many files) create a `TChain` and `Add` the input files. and from there on use either the `TChain` or the `TTree` with `SetBranchAddress` and `GetEntry`.

Comment: yeah-- I realized that later and now only have compchain->Add("file")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you don't need to use the `comp_tree` pointer at all. The `compchain` pointer should be enough to access the data in the `TTree` because `TChain` is a `TTree`. Therefore, you should be able to "link" the variables to the chain/tree branches as:

```
compchain->SetBranchAddress("_compression",&_compression);
```

instead of

```
comp_tree->SetBranchAddress("_compression",&_compression);
```